# Grabbing title of page from an API is alerting undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, wikipedia-api

This bit of code below scans an API on Wikipedia, and then is supposed to alert the title of it by getting the JSON property "title". However, it just alerts `undefined`, and for some reason, it alerts it twice. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Twitter', function(data){
  for (var Object in data){
    var Info = data[Object]
    var Title = Info["title"]
    alert(Title)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Twitter', function(data) {
  $.each(data.query.pages, function( index, value ) {
    var title = value.title;
    alert(title);
  });
})
```

The query returns a `data` object, which has a `query` object within it, and one/multiple `pages` within that. Iterate over each page, and grab the `title` string.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcaneCraeda/2pf8v0nc/2/)

Note: You may want to learn to use your browser's debugging tools, and read up on the JSON format.